# How do I change the position of the label in the Nodes of ReactFlow?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-flow

I am trying to change the position of the label of reactflow node from Center to the left side and rotate it 90deg, for example something like this.[image]  can anyone tell me how I can achive this

I tried using chatgpt but it couldn't help, Searched google but no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom node in reactflow and then customize it to exhibit the above behavior. The custom node can be implemented as below.

```html
<div id="text-rotate">
  <p>Label</p>
</div>
```

```html
#text-rotate {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```